# Find string words in database column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product table in database. And database engine is **innodb**.

Now, product table has a product_name field. Here, I want to get all record of product table whose product name match with the given string.

For example, Laptop is a product_name and my string is " I want laptop". Now, I want to find product_name that contains in a string.

I have written query like :

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE MATCH (product_name) AGAINST ('I want laptop');
```

But this query throw an error like **(The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes)** because of my database engine innodb. So which query should i have to write instead of it?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your problem, you will need

- Either to change your your table's engine type to [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) which supports Full-Text Search (in case you use MySQL version prior to 5.6).
- Or use [InnoDB Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) (MySQL version 5.6 and later).

Comment: i have changed innodb engine to MyISAM but it throw same error and my sql version is 5.5.44-37.3-log - Percona Server.

Comment: Are you sure the engine type is successfully set? Please type on your Terminal `show table status where name = 'product';` and check the engine type.@Nisarg
`

Comment: Yes. I am sure about it. I have exuecute your query then is gives enigine as MyISAM.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `like` with double wild cards but the query will be very slow because double wild card queries can't use an index so the db will be forced to do a table scan:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE 'I want laptop' LIKE CONCAT('%',product_name,'%');
```

Comment: If by mistake user can write lap  top instead of laptop so it will not written any row. But I want that row so what query should have to write?

Comment: @Nisarg i don't think there is an equivalent alternative